# Merge two tibbles/data frames with different row lengths

Tags: r

How can I merge two tibbles with different lengths? I want something like `full_join` in dplyr but keeping all columns, respectively without `"by"`. In general `cbind` works fine but have problems with different lengths.

If I have two data frames:

```
a <- data.frame(Test=1:4,
                TestB=5:6)
b <- data.frame(TEST=1:10,
                TestB=11:20)
```

And If I want to combine them the output should look like:

```
aa <- data.frame(Test=c(1:4,rep(0,6)),
                 TestB=c(5:6,rep(0,8)),
                 TEST=1:10,
                 TestB=11:20)
```

Comment: Add an example, please!

Comment: How do you define "length" of a tibble? You mean dimensions? Is the difference in row number, column number, both?

Comment: Would you like to merge two tibble of different lenght ( I suppose numbers of rows) without a by clause like in `merge()`? Which logic do you suppose to have to merge them? I mean, `merge()`, uses ids, cbind puts one to one.

Comment: I will give you an example:

Comment: @Christian you can delete this post / question, as you've created this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673607/combine-two-data-frames-or-tibbles/51673855#51673855