# combine two data frames or tibbles

Tags: r

I have the following data frames:

```
a <- data.frame(Test=1:4,
            TestA=5:6)
> a
    Test TestA
1    1     5
2    2     6
3    3     5
4    4     6


b <- data.frame(TEST=1:10,
            TestB=11:20)

> b
    TEST TestB
1     1    11
2     2    12
3     3    13
4     4    14
5     5    15
6     6    16
7     7    17
8     8    18
9     9    19
10   10    20
```

And I want to combine them such that the result looks like:

```
    Test TestA TEST   TestB
1     1     5    1      11
2     2     6    2      12
3     3     5    3      13
4     4     6    4      14
5     0     0    5      15
6     0     0    6      16
7     0     0    7      17
8     0     0    8      18
9     0     0    9      19
10    0     0   10      20
```

That is, to combine with unmatched rows filled with zeros.

I am convinced that a simple solution exists and it would be fine if there is a way with `dplyr`.

Comment: Why column `TestA` in your result data set is not `5,6,5,6,0,....`?

Comment: Sorry, should be `5,6,5,6,0,...`

Answer (score 3):

You can combine two data frames using `merge()`.

```
df<-merge(x=a,y=b,by.x="Test",by.y = "TEST",all= T)
```

The above produces:

```
   Test TestA TestB
1     1     5    11
2     2     6    12
3     3     5    13
4     4     6    14
5     5    NA    15
6     6    NA    16
7     7    NA    17
8     8    NA    18
9     9    NA    19
10   10    NA    20
```

If you want `Test` and `TEST` separate, you can create an ID column for both, and replace `by.x` and `by.y` with that ID variable.

To replace NAs with 0s, you can use `df$TestA[is.na(TestA)]<-0`. Same for `Test` if you want to keep both `Test` and `TEST`.

Answer (score 1):

With data.table, you could

1. pre-fill 0s in `b` and then
2. update-join values in from `a`

like...

```
# input
a <- data.frame(Test=1:4, TestA=5:6)
b <- data.frame(TEST=1:10, TestB=11:20)
library(data.table)
setDT(a); setDT(b)

# prefill
b[, c("Test", "TestA") := 0L]

# update join
b[a, on=.(TEST = Test), c("Test", "TestA") := .(i.Test, i.TestA)]

    TEST TestB Test TestA
 1:    1    11    1     5
 2:    2    12    2     6
 3:    3    13    3     5
 4:    4    14    4     6
 5:    5    15    0     0
 6:    6    16    0     0
 7:    7    17    0     0
 8:    8    18    0     0
 9:    9    19    0     0
10:   10    20    0     0
```

This modifies `b` instead of creating a new table. This works for your example, but if you need a "full join" (where `b` doesn't have the full set of rows you want in the final table), another answer will fit better.

On the other hand, if your table has real NAs that you don't want filled with zeros, this is a better approach than the first few answers (which overwrite all NAs, not just those resulting from a row being unmatched in the tables' join/merge/combination).

---

To generalize to more columns, define a list of `default` values...

```
# input
a <- data.frame(Test=1:4, TestA=5:6)
b <- data.frame(TEST=1:10, TestB=11:20)

library(data.table)
setDT(a); setDT(b)    
defaults = list(Test = 0L, TestA = 0L)
new_cols = names(defaults)

# prefill defaults
b[, (new_cols) := defaults]

# update join
b[a, on=.(TEST = Test), (new_cols) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", new_cols))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unusual to want the Test column repeated and to want 0s instead of NAs, but exactly as you ask would be:

```
library(dplyr)
b$Test <- b$TEST
c <- full_join(a,b, by="Test")
c$Test[is.na(c$TestA)] <-0
c$TestA[is.na(c$TestA)] <-0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- merge(a, b, by = 0, all = TRUE,sort = FALSE)[-1]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
   Test TestA TEST TestB
1     1     5    1    11
2     2     6    2    12
3     3     5    3    13
4     4     6    4    14
5     0     0    5    15
6     0     0    6    16
7     0     0    7    17
8     0     0    8    18
9     0     0    9    19
10    0     0   10    20
```

Comment: perfect, thank you, pretty simple, that's exactely what I've searched. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
# example datasets
a <- data.frame(Test=1:4,
                TestA=5:6)

b <- data.frame(TEST=1:10,
                TestB=11:20)

library(dplyr)

a %>%
  mutate(TEST = Test) %>%                        # duplicate Test column and give the name TEST
  full_join(b, by="TEST") %>%                    # full join 
  mutate_at(vars(Test, TestA), ~coalesce(.,0L))  # replace NAs with 0s for those two variables

#    Test TestA TEST TestB
# 1     1     5    1    11
# 2     2     6    2    12
# 3     3     5    3    13
# 4     4     6    4    14
# 5     0     0    5    15
# 6     0     0    6    16
# 7     0     0    7    17
# 8     0     0    8    18
# 9     0     0    9    19
# 10    0     0   10    20
```

You can also use `mutate_all(~coalesce(.,0L))`, but no need to look all columns for NAs if you know that they will exist only on those two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use package `sqldf` :

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM b LEFT JOIN a on a.test = B.test")
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#    Test TestA TEST TestB
# 1     1     5    1    11
# 2     2     6    2    12
# 3     3     5    3    13
# 4     4     6    4    14
# 5     0     0    5    15
# 6     0     0    6    16
# 7     0     0    7    17
# 8     0     0    8    18
# 9     0     0    9    19
# 10    0     0   10    20
```

Or using only `SQL`, leveraging the function `coalesce` as @G. Grothendieck mentions:

```
sqldf("SELECT coalesce(a.Test, 0) Test, coalesce(a.TestA, 0) TestA, b.* FROM b LEFT JOIN a using(test)")
```